# Office Graph TrendingAround always return 403 Forbidden

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

The call to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/trendingAround returns "403 Forbidden" although the App has File.Read permissions.

I've checked 
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes and didn't find any more appropriate privilege to give. I even tried to give all permissions listed on **dev.office.com/app-registration** but the response is the same.

The call to **graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people** works.

If I try the trendingAround API on **graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer** it also works, but not in the App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[List trendingAround](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_trendingaround) API requires **Sites.Read.All** permission which is not list in https://dev.office.com/app-registration. You need to assign this permission in Azure Active Directory.

1. Go to the Office 365 tenant in Azure AD > Applications.

[image]

2. Find the application your registered or register a new one.
3. Microsoft Graph > Delegated Permissions > Read Items in all site collections.

[image]

For more details, please check the document [Manually register your app with Azure AD so it can access Office 365 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually)